# Scala XML: Descendant vs Child

Tags: xml, scala

What's the difference between Node.descendant and Node.child?

```
scala> val n = <a b="c">d</a>.asInstanceOf[xml.Node]
n: scala.xml.Node = <a b="c">d</a>

scala> n.descendant
res22: List[scala.xml.Node] = List(d)

scala> n.child
res23: Seq[scala.xml.Node] = ArrayBuffer(d)
```

I thought maybe it behaves differently for other element types. But it's the same for Text.

```
scala> val t = n.child.head.asInstanceOf[xml.Text]
t: scala.xml.Text = d

scala> t.descendant
res24: List[scala.xml.Node] = List()

scala> t.child
res25: object Nil = List()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically descendant in XML lingo would include a child or grand-child (chilf of child, and so on); whereas child is just an immediate child (element immediately contained within parent element).

Comment: Correct! Thanks. (Need to wait 3 mins before clicking the tick). :)